Using MOSFET to Control 2 LEDs Separately from Same 12V Source
I am trying to control 2 LEDs from a model railway decoder. The decoder has a common positive terminal (+12 V).
The decoder also has a two negative terminals - one I have called FL and the other I have called AUX1. I have used switches in this diagram to represent and simplify the inner workings of the decoder i.e. when the corresponding command is sent to the decoder it 'switches on' the FL and AUX1 terminals
I want the D1 LED to illuminate when FL is switched on. I want the D2 LED to illuminate only when both the FL and AUX1 are switched on.
Am I right in thinking I need to use a P-channel MOSFET? Would the circuit below work?
Am I also right in thinking that when Switch 2 is closed the source-gate voltage difference of -12 V would switch the MOSFET on?
However, I am struggling to figure out whether the MOSFET would be switched off when switch 2 is open. If this is the case, how could the circuit be adapted to make this happen?
Any help would be much appreciated! I have previously used logic level N-channel MOSFETs to switch large currents so have some understanding of the basic principles but am by no means an expert.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

With the circuit as drawn, be sure that D1 and D2 are "12V LEDs" (LED assembly with built in current limiting resistor) or add the current limiting resistor in series with D1 and D2

You would simply add a "pull-up" resistor between SW2 and R1 that connects to the 12V rail. 10k would be a suitable value.

This is your circuit redrawn to make it easy to understand its function, and with one small modification to make it work:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I've represented your "12V LEDs" with their built-in resistors R1 and R2, because I don't want to give anyone the impression that it's OK to connect a normal LED (without such resistors) directly across a 12V supply.
You don't need a resistance in series with Q1's gate. Instead, I've used resistance R3 to hold the gate at high potential when SW2 is open, making Q1's \$V_{GS}=0V\$ to keep it off.
Here's another version which will also do what you ask, with a slight "advantage", perhaps:

simulate this circuit
Here I use switch SW2 to pass LED current also. SW1 passes only D1 current, but still controls gate potential. In this way, you don't have a single switch/channel being required to handle current for both LEDs. That may not be important unless you are nearing current limits for those channels.
Resistor R3 may not be necessary, but is recommended, to keep Q1 off, with \$V_{FL}=+12V\$ and \$V_{SG}=0V\$ when SW1 is open, instead of relying on the extremely high impedance of D1 to do that.
LED D1 will illuminate if switch SW1 is closed, regardless of the state of SW2.
MOSFET Q1 is switched on when its gate is low in potential, which can only occur if switch SW1 is closed, making \$V_{FL}=0V\$ and Q1 \$V_{SG}=12V\$. However, switch SW2 must also be closed making \$V_{AUX1}=0V\$, for any current to flow via LED D2, so both switches must be closed for D2 to illuminate.

Hi Simon, That is incredibly helpful, thank you so much. I will prototype the circuit when the p channel MOSFETs arrive and see if it works. Thanks again.


I want the D1 LED to illuminate when FL is switched on. I want the D2
LED to illuminate only when both the FL and AUX1 are switched on.

I am considering the above is what you are trying to achieve.
For this, you can try the following circuit (Logic):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Note: use proper current limiting resisters for the LEDs.
Let me know in comments if this is not what you are looking for.
You can use SPDT SSRs to implement the SW2 logic for simplicity.

Is D1 active when both SW1 and SW2 are?
